# Terraform single-file modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-module

I've been reading up the Terraform standard module structure and I see they want a main, outputs, and variables file in every one.

I have a pair of modules where everything fits in a single tmux window, is it really worth breaking out into three files for such a small module or is this a rule that is really only applied at scale?

Answer (score 3):

While it's best practice to use `variables.tf` and `outputs.tf`, both variables and outputs can be declared in any file - so in a way it just boils down to both personal preference along with any formatting rules that may exist in your project or team.

Personally, I prefer to always use these files as it helps me keep things tidy and organized.